# Access violation occurs in GetHttpConnection () method

Tags: c++, visual-c++

You are creating a program to download files from the specified URL in VC ++ 2012.
Part to be downloaded as a DLL, we're calling from the main program.
In this case, when you run the GetHttpConnection () method, an access violation occurs.
We examined various, but did not know.
Please lend your wisdom.

main.exe

```
    :
    :
    :
hModule = LoadLibraryW(currentDirectory);
DLL_GetHttp = (FUNC_DLL_GetHttp)GetProcAddress(hModule, "GetHttp");
    :
    :
    :
CHttpConnection* pConnection = NULL;
CInternetSession session;
CHttpFile* pFile = NULL; 

BYTE* pRecvBuf;
ULONG pnRecvSize;
ULONG lRet;


lRet = DLL_GetHttp(&pConnection, &session, &pFile, downloadFile, NULL, 0, &pRecvBuf, &pnRecvSize);
   :
   :
```

http.dll

```
ULONG GetHttp(CHttpConnection** pConnection, CInternetSession* session, CHttpFile** pFile, LPCTSTR url, BYTE* pSendBuf, ULONG nSendSize, BYTE** pRecvBuf, ULONG* pnRecvSize) 
{ 
    *pRecvBuf = NULL; 
    *pnRecvSize = 0; 
    LONG nRet = 0; 

    DWORD dwServiceType; 
    CString strServer; 
    CString strObject; 
    INTERNET_PORT nPort; 
    CString strConnectUrl;

    strConnectUrl = url;

    AFX_MANAGE_STATE( AfxGetStaticModuleState() );

    if (!AfxParseURL(url, dwServiceType, strServer, strObject, nPort)) 
    { 
        // ASSERT(0); 
        return ERROR_PARAMETOR; 
    } 


    try 
    { 
        (*pConnection) = (*session).GetHttpConnection(       // access error!!!!
            strServer, 
            INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD | INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE , 
            nPort, 
            NULL, 
            NULL 
        ); 

        DWORD dwFlags = INTERNET_FLAG_EXISTING_CONNECT | INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD | INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE; 
        BOOL bSecure = strConnectUrl.MakeLower().Find(_T("https")) == 0; 
        if (bSecure) 
        { 
            dwFlags |= INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE; 
        } 

        *pFile = (*pConnection)->OpenRequest( 
            CHttpConnection::HTTP_VERB_POST, 
            strObject, 
            NULL, 
            1, 
            NULL, 
            _T("HTTP/1.1"), 
            dwFlags 
        ); 

        :
        :
        :
```

Comment: So which line in the code you posted gives an access violation?

Comment: (*pConnection) = (*session).GetHttpConnection(       // access error!!!!
            strServer, 
            INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD | INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE , 
            nPort, 
            NULL, 
            NULL 
        );

Comment: What are the values of `pConnection`, `session`, `strServer`?

Comment: What's `FUNC_DLL_GetHttp`?

Comment: typedef ULONG (*FUNC_GetHttp)(CHttpConnection** pConnection, CInternetSession* session, CHttpFile** pFile, LPCTSTR url, BYTE* pSendBuf, ULONG nSendSize, BYTE** pRecvBuf, ULONG* pnRecvSize);

FUNC_GetHttp DLL_GetHttp;

Comment: pConnection: I will create an instance in GetHttpConnection ().

Comment: session: CInternetSession

Comment: strServer: http://rss.dailynews.yahoo.co.jp/fc/domestic/rss.xml

Comment: @user4276852 I asked for the values of those variables, not what types they are.  If you're really debugging this, the first thing you should have posted were the values to these variables.  Are you debugging your code?